# Ruby file force copy

Tags: ruby, file, copy

Is there a way to get ruby to do a forced copy? FileUtils.cp_r seems not to have a :force => true option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, but it does have `:remove_destination` as an option, which does much the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using [`FileUtils.cp`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp) to copy a single file, overwriting the target file if it exists is the default behavior; no "force" or similar option is necessary.